# Proof the limit of a sequence equals infinity

Tags: limits, infinity, epsilon-delta

Prove, using the definition of $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty $, that

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{4x+\sqrt{5}}{2x^3+x^2} = \infty$

We know the definiton as:

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty $

if, for all $K > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert > K$, when $0 < \lvert x -a\rvert < \delta$

In our case:

$f(x) = \frac{4x+\sqrt{5}}{2x^3+x^2}$

$a = 0$

From the defintion:

$\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}}{2x^3+x^2} > K$, when  $\lvert x -a\rvert = \lvert x \rvert <\delta$

Where do we go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $4x+\sqrt{5}>4x$  so

$$\frac{4x+\sqrt{5}}{2x^3+x^2} > \frac{4x}{2x^3+x^2}>K$$
if $$\frac{4}{2x^2+x}>K$$

we know $K>0;\;x>0$ so the inequality is solved when $$0<x<\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{K+32}{K}}-\frac{1}{4}$$

So for any $K>0$ if $$|x|<\delta=\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{K+32}{K}}-\frac{1}{4}$$
then $f(x)>K$

For instance if $K=1000$ then $\delta=0.0039$

Taking $x=0.001<\delta$ we have $$f(x)=\frac{4\cdot 0.001+\sqrt{5}}{2\cdot 0.001^3+0.001^2}\approx 2.23\times 10^6>K$$

Hope this helps